# Thottle PHP script from json Facebook api feed

Tags: php, sql, json, facebook-graph-api

I have a script that runs in the background over facebook api using json_decode however it is bogging down my server to the point where i cannot connect. I am having it loop over all the tags in side my own personal photo album. Is there a way i can limit the connections/decodes/etc so that my server does not die?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run it on a separate server, and then feed the data into your database.

You may want to look at php-resque  (YMMV), I haven't used php and resque...